# I am trying to find a channel by a certain keyword that can be anywhere in the name of the channel

Tags: discord, discord.js

```
let GChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find((x) => (x.name.includes === "giveaway"))
    if (!GChannel) message.reply("Giveaway Channel Found")
   GChannel.send("Hello")
```

Like we have `message.content.includes`, is there anyway to find a channel as well which **includes the keyword giveaway**?
The Error Code I Get is pretty obvious.

```
> GChannel.send("Hello")
>              ^ TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
```

Like the bot should **find the channel with a name that includes giveaway**. Is there anyway of doing that?

Thanks <3!

Answer (score 0):

[`String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) is a function, not a string, and thus must be called as a function.

```js
let GChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find((x) => x.name.includes("giveaway"))
```

Comment: Doesnt work. I just tested

TypeError: x.name.includes.includes is not a function

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my end. Remove the first `includes`

Comment: Glad I could help. Make sure to mark my answer as accepted if it solved your problem so that it's easier to find in the future for people who shared your issue.